# Closed-form solution of $\mathbb{R}^2$ LASSO?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The problem:

$$\min_{x, \, y} \quad (ax + by + 1)^2 + |x| + |y| + (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2$$

where all variables are in $\mathbb{R}$. Can I find the optimal ($x_p,y_p$) in terms of $a$ and $b$?

**Edited:**
I have tried two ways:

1. One way is to set the (sub-) gradients to zero:
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   2a(ax_p + by_p + 1) + \text{sign}(x_p) + 2(x_p-1) = 0 \\
   2b(ax_p + by_p + 1) + \text{sign}(y_p) + 2(y_p-1) = 0 
   \end{cases}
   \quad\Rightarrow\quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   x_p \\
   y_p 
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   2a^2 + 2 & 2ab \\
   2ab & 2b^2 + 2
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   2 - 2a - \text{sign}(x_p)\\
   2 - 2b - \text{sign}(y_p)\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   For convex problems (as in our case) this is the optimal. However the sign tangles into the final expression.
2. Another way is to split the problem as:
   $$\min_{x, \, y} \quad \underbrace{(ax + by + 1)^2 + (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2}_{f(x,y)} + \underbrace{|x| + |y|}_{g(x,y)} $$
   Geometrically, the optimal $(x_p,y_p)$ would be a convex combination of $(x_0,y_0)$ (the optimal of $f$) and the origin $(0,0)$ (the optimal of $g$). That said
   $$(x_p,y_p) = (t_x x_0, t_y y_0)$$ where $t_x, t_y$ are in $[0,1]$. $(x_0,y_0)$ can be easily obtained by letting $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$:
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   x_0 \\
   y_0 
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   2a^2 + 2 & 2ab \\
   2ab & 2b^2 + 2
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   2 - 2a\\
   2 - 2b\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   For $(x_p,y_p)$ obtained from Method 1, the tangled sign can be determiend from $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? I wouldn't be surprised if a closed-form solution exists in this very limited case, but generally it is not good to expect Math.SE members to do _all_ the work for you.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Without the terms $(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2$ it is trivial: projection from the origin to the line $ax + by + 1 = 0$. However with the term it is a little complicated. Simply setting the (sub-)gradient to zero yields an equation with undetermined signs... It would complicate the computations. So I am humbly asking the community.

Comment: @WDC, You better show the steps you made so far for the *undetermined signs*.

Comment: @Royi Please see the edits. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, like I said, I wouldn’t be _surprised_ if a closed form solution exists. But it’s not looking promising.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I know my approach looks ugly. I wonder if there are easier ways to go.

Comment: It’s not that it’s ugly! It’s a good attempt. I am simply not sure that a closed form solution exists.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks for saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the closest to a closed-form solution you can get is using duality. Taking
$$
\mathbf{z} = (x, y)^T, \quad
\mathbf{b} = (-1, 1, 1)^T , \quad
\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ 1&0 \\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
your problem is
$$
\min_{\mathbf{z}} \quad \|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{b}\|_2^2 + \|\mathbf{z}\|_1.
$$
Adding the constraint $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{z}$ we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\mathbf{z}} &\quad \|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{b}\|_2^2 + \|\mathbf{w}\|_1 \\
\text{s.t.} &\quad \mathbf{w}-\mathbf{z}=0
\end{aligned}
$$
The Lagrangian is
$$
L(\mathbf{z}, \mathbf{w}; \mathbf{u}) = \|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{b}\|_2^2 + \|\mathbf{w}\|_1 + \mathbf{u}^T(\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{z}).
$$
Therefore, the dual objective is
$$
q(\mathbf{u}) = \min_{\mathbf{z}} \{ \|\mathbf{A} \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{b}\|_2^2 + \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{z} \} + \min_{\mathbf{w}} \{ \|\mathbf{w}\|_1 - \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{w}\}
$$
The second optimization problem has a very simple solution, the indicator function of the set $\{ \mathbf{u} : \|\mathbf{u}\|_{\infty} \leq 1\}$. The rightmost optimization problem is a convex quadratic problem whose optimal solution, obtained by $\nabla = 0$, is
$$
\mathbf{z}^* = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{A^T A})^{-1}(2 \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{u})
$$
and the optimal value is
$$
-\frac{1}{4} (\mathbf{u} - 2\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b})^T (\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A})^{-1} (\mathbf{u} - 2\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b}) - \|\mathbf{b}\|_2^2.
$$
So the dual problem, up to constants, is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\mathbf{u}} &\quad -(\mathbf{u} - 2\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b})^T (\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A})^{-1} (\mathbf{u} - 2\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b}) \\
\text{s.t.} &\quad -1 \leq u_1 \leq 1 \\
 &\quad -1 \leq u_2 \leq 1
\end{aligned}
$$

The dual is easily solved by KKT by solving 16 linear equations which arise from the signs of the Lagrange multiplies (zero or nonzero). The primal solution is obtained from the dual optimal $u^*$ by the formula found earlier:
$$
\mathbf{z}^* = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{A^T A})^{-1}(2 \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{u}^*)
$$

## Important

Note, that when solving the dual, you can avoid inverting matrices altogether. Just explicitly write the equations, and use the fact that you already know the inverse of $(\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A})^{-1}$.

Comment: Could you expand a little on the KKT part? For me: let $\mathbf{s}$ be the multiplier, KKT gives me (i) $\nabla = 0$; (ii) $\mathbf{s}^{T}(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{1}) = \mathbf{0}$; (iii) $\mathbf{u} \leq \mathbf{1}$. I have difficulties recognizing them as linear systems. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Yes. But first, note that (ii) are *not* the CS conditions, and you forgot the non-negativity of $\mathbf{s}$. So the right CS conditions are $s_1(u_1 - 1) = 0$ and $s_2(u_2 - 1) = 0$, and you also have the constraints $s_1, s_2 \geq 0$.

Now, assume, for example, that $s_1 = 0, s_2 > 0$. In that case, the first CS condition trivially holds, and you have the linear equation $s_1 = 0$. In the second CS condition you can divide by $s_2 > 0$ and get $u_2 = 1$, which is linear. Doing so for all 4 options of the signs of $s_1, s_2$ yields four linear systems, since $\nabla = 0$ is also linear.

Comment: Oh.. now I noticed I made a different mistake. The constraint $\|\mathbf{u}\|_\infty \leq 1$ is, in fact, $-1 \leq u_1 \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq u_2 \leq 1$. Thus, you will have four multipliers and therefore 16 linear systems to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the expansion but I still didn't get the point... Sorry for that. So after solving all 16 linear systems I would have 4 solutions of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, and one of them is the optimal $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{s})$. How can I identify the one out of 4? Will there be only one valid solution? If so, to me it is another "sign-tangled" version that the optimal cannot be "catch out" at once.

Comment: The problems (both primal and dual) are convex. For a convex problem, *any* point satisfyint KKT is optimal. And you do not need all dual optimal points, you need just one. You go over the linear systems one by one, solve each of them, and verify that the rest of the inequality conditions in the KKT system hold. If they do not hold, you continue to the next linear system. If they do hold, you found a KKT point, and it must be optimal.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks again for your solution. Finally I endup doing the solution using my Method 2, for the sake of GPU (where conditional statements are time-consuming). I will upvote your answer when I got enough reps. Thanks again for the dual LASSO approach.